# Dropdown binding error null pointer exception

Tags: c#, asp.net

On binding dropdown null pointer exception through. `Datatable` has a table with two columns `CategoryId` and `CategoryName`.

```
DataTable ds1 = SweepBeatRegistration.GetAreaCoverageCategory();

ddlAreaCoverageCategory.DataSource = ds1;

ddlAreaCoverageCategory.DataTextField = "CategoryName";
ddlAreaCoverageCategory.DataValueField = "ID";

ddlAreaCoverageCategory.DataBind();
ddlAreaCoverageCategory.SelectedValue = "0";
```

Comment: That's not a full code, so I guess you need to get an instance of SweepBeatRegistration first.

Comment: I have Update panel also on .aspx page do you think this may also effect binding?

Comment: this page inherits by  master page that have contentplaceholder in datalist Item template that is why I was unable to set values for controls and through null pointer exception. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to be

```
ddlAreaCoverageCategory.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

Or

```
ddlAreaCoverageCategory.Items.FindByValue("SomeValue").Selected = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the column name is `CategoryId` then you should have:

```
ddlAreaCoverageCategory.DataValueField = "CategoryId";
```